# Kafka Connect JDBC sink connector nested avro

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to run a Kafka connect sink for oracle database. The avro message in kafka is nested.

The message looks something like this:

```
    {
      "header" : {
        "id" : "",
        "source" : "",
        "name" : ""
      },
      "somefields" : {
        "something" : "value",
         "other" : "its value",

           }
}
```

My question is :

Is this possible to achieve using Kafka connect? If so how? I remember reading somewhere nested structures are not supported. Is it true if so why?
I am getting an error saying :

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException:(STRUCT) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.DbDialect.getSqlType(DbDialect.java:202)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.OracleDialect.getSqlType(OracleDialect.java:73)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.DbDialect.writeColumnSpec(DbDialect.java:140)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.DbDialect$3.apply(DbDialect.java:132)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.DbDialect$3.apply(DbDialect.java:128)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.StringBuilderUtil.joinToBuilder(StringBuilderUtil.java:54)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.StringBuilderUtil.joinToBuilder(StringBuilderUtil.java:37)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.DbDialect.writeColumnsSpec(DbDialect.java:128)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.DbDialect.getCreateQuery(DbDialect.java:96)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.create(DbStructure.java:87)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.createOrAmendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:62)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:66)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:62)
```

Any help or advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't have a mapping because what datatype in Oracle supports nested data? I think the best you would get is a BLOB

Comment: So if we use Postgres would that solve our issue?

Comment: I can't answer that, but that's also not what I was trying to ask

Comment: There's nothing necessarily wrong with Oracle for this process. You however need an external Kafka Connect message transform that flattens the data https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/flatten.html  or you need a separate Kafka process that'll do that for you and produce to a separate topic, which you put into Connect

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into that.

Comment: @cricket_007 I would really appreciate if you could let me know how do we use it with kafka connect. There's a little documentation on how do we integrate with existing source or sinks.

Comment: Use what? Transforms are documented here http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms and in the confluent blogs https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks a lot! That blog was really helpful!

Comment: @cricket_007 The flatten transform doesn't work with array types. At least it didn't for me. It threw an error saying "Flatten transformation does not support ARRAY for record without schemas". Not sure what it means by 'without schemas' since it clearly had an avro schema which it read successfully from the registry. Do you know of a way around this?

Comment: @emirhosseini Flatten works for structs, which have schemas. This question has no arrays... But a plain JSON array would have no schema.